# Distance from a specific geo position

Tags: elasticsearch

Im building a tourist app, with its search capability implemented using Elasticsearch.
I have indexed the details of the bus stations and their geographical positions as shown in the document  below
sample doc

```
{
"name": "North Stand",
"location": {
"lat": 1.1,
"lon": 1.54
}
}
```

So one of its features is to find the distance to nearby bus stations from the users current position. How can I do that in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the geo_distance_range filter/query . [geo_distance_range](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/query-dsl-geo-distance-range-query.html)

But first of all you need to map the location as geoPoint.

```
{
"bool" : {
    "must" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "filter" : {
        "geo_distance_range" : {
            "from" : "2km",
            "to" : "6km",
            "location" : {
                "lat": 1.1,
                "lon": 1.54
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```